# Set as default application is not working (opening pdf files): Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: pdf, evince

I want to open my pdf file with evince (document viewer) as the default application.
I right-click on the pdf, *properties*, *open with* and the Default application is ImageMagick

I try to change it by clicking on Document Viewer (or Okular), then *set as default* and nothing changes.

In the file

`etc/gnome/defaults.list`

I see this line

```
application/pdf=evince.desktop
```

But ImageMagick is the default.  I can't purge ImageMagick because it will remove one package that I need.

Do you know any workaround to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find this file: /home/yourusername/.config/mimeapps.list
And replace "application/pdf=blablabla" line to this;

```
application/pdf=evince.desktop;
```

(If not exist line, add to "[Added Associations]".)

Tested and works in Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04, 20.04